# Automatically assigned marker colors for markers within a group too similar, anyway to get unique colors assigned?

Tags: markers, color

Automatically assigned marker colors for markers within a group are too similar, is there anyway to get unique colors assigned?

I could go through the symbology of each marker and manually change them to a distinct color or but this would take forever for the 70 or so unique markers I want to display. I've tried to use categorized markers with the value set as the unique species names, but the issue is when I paste this style to the others it makes all the styles the same color and shape.

this is on qgis

Comment: Which software/platform do you use?

Comment: Be aware that more than 10 colours are bad practice from a cartographic point of view, since hard to distinguish. Consider including different forms and/or patterns.

Comment: sorry, the initial post should say colors or shapes. the issue is the same though , how can I paste a style of a unique shapes without overwriting the unique colors of the marker I'm pasting on